# Numba does not recognize numpy.maximum.accumulate(), how to revise the following code?

Tags: python-2.7, numba

Error message: TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Unknown attribute 'accumulate' of type Function().

How to revise the following code? Thank you.

```
import numba
import numpy as np


@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def maxdd(x):
    temp = np.maximum.accumulate(x) - x
    ide = len(x) - np.argmax(temp[::-1]) - 1
    ids = np.argmax(x[:ide])
    mdd = x[ide] - x[ids]
    ide += 1
    return mdd, ids, ide
```

Answer (score 4):

I have tried using vectorized ufunc to calculate running maximum in this way:

```
@numba.vectorize(["int32(int32,int32)","int64(int64,int64)","float32(float32,float32)"])
@numba.njit()
def nmax(x, y):
    if x>y:
        return x
    else:
        return y
@numba.njit()
def test():
    a = np.arange(12)[::-1]
    print(a)
    return nmax.accumulate(a)
test()
```

However, in Numba 0.46.0 this throws error

> Unknown attribute 'accumulate' of type Function(numba._DUFunc 'nmax')

as currently it seems that Numba can't work with vectorized functions in nopython mode (?), unfortunately, cause un-njiting test gives expected

> [11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0]
>
> array([11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11])

For now we have to manually code such function as

```
@numba.njit()
def running_max(x):
    rmax=x[0]
    y=np.empty_like(x)
    for i,val in enumerate(x):
        if val>rmax: rmax=val
        y[i]=rmax
    return y
```

I have raised an [issue](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/4969) with Numba team.

Answer (score 4):

I came across the same problem and wanted to elaborate on Anatoly's answer for how to get around this. As mentioned, `.accumulate` is not supported by `numba`. However, the `numpy` [documentation on `.accumulate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html) provides a hint:

```
For a one-dimensional array, accumulate produces results equivalent to:

r = np.empty(len(A))
t = op.identity        # op = the ufunc being applied to A's  elements
for i in range(len(A)):
    t = op(t, A[i])
    r[i] = t
return r
```

So, let's first convert this to a proper function:

```
def numba_maximum_accumulate(A):
    r = np.empty(len(A))
    t = op.identity
    for i in range(len(A)):
        t = op(t, A[i])
        r[i] = t
    return r
```

Next, we swap out `op` for our desired operation `np.maximum`

```
def numba_maximum_accumulate(A):
    r = np.empty(len(A))
    t = np.maximum.identity
    for i in range(len(A)):
        t = np.maximum(t, A[i])
        r[i] = t
    return r
```

However, we'll quickly learn that the [`identity`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.identity.html) of `np.maximum` is `None` and this is undesirable and, instead, we should seed this process by simply setting `t = np.-inf` (Note that in the case of `np.minimum`, you'll want to seed with `t = np.inf` instead).

```
def numba_maximum_accumulate(A):
    r = np.empty(len(A))
    t = -np.inf
    for i in range(len(A)):
        t = np.maximum(t, A[i])
        r[i] = t
    return r
```

Finally, let's JIT our function:

```
from numba import njit

@njit()
def numba_maximum_accumulate(A):
    r = np.empty(len(A))
    t = -np.inf
    for i in range(len(A)):
        t = np.maximum(t, A[i])
        r[i] = t
    return r
```

Now you should be able to call this function on your data.